# Tensorflow Non-Maximum Suppression

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

NOTE: [`tf.image.non_max_suppression`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/non_max_suppression) does NOT do what I'm looking for!

I'm trying to perform non-maximum suppression (NMS) similar to the [Canny edge detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Non-maximum_suppression). Specifically, NMS on an 2D array will keep a value if it is the maximum within a window, otherwise suppress it (set to 0).

For example, consider the matrix

`[[3 2 1 4 2 3]
  [1 4 2 1 5 2]
  [2 2 3 2 1 3]]`

If we consider a window size of `3 x 3`, then the result should be

`[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 4 0 0 5 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0]]`

I've searched around and couldn't find anything that performs this operation in `tf.image` and `tf.nn`. Is there code somewhere that performs NMS? If not, how can I efficiently implement NMS in Tensorflow (Python)?

Thanks!

EDIT: I came up with one way to solve this but I'm not sure if there are better ways: take a max pool with 1 stride (i.e. no downsampling) and the window size, then use `tf.where` to check if the value is equal to the max pooled value and set to 0 if not. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question (though open to better solutions):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def non_max_suppression(input, window_size):
    # input: B x W x H x C
    pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(input, ksize=[1, window_size, window_size, 1], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    output = tf.where(tf.equal(input, pooled), input, tf.zeros_like(input))

    # NOTE: if input has negative values, the suppressed values can be higher than original
    return output # output: B X W X H x C

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = np.array([[3,2,1,4,2,3],[1,4,2,1,5,2],[2,2,3,2,1,3]], dtype=np.float32).reshape([1,3,6,1])
inp = tf.Variable(x)
out = non_max_suppression(inp, 3)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print out.eval().reshape([3,6])
'''
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  0.  0.  5.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
'''

sess.close()
```

Comment: It looks like the method to get unpooling indexes.